# Is this binomial coefficient identity known?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

I stumbled across this identity involving binomial coefficients this morning:

If $n$, $k$, $a$, and $b$ are positive integers and $n=a+b$, then

$$ \binom{n}{k} =\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{a}{k-i}\binom{b}{i}.$$

The proof is trivial. (Partition a set $N$ of $n$ things into disjoint sets $A$ of $a$ things and $B$ of $b$ things. Now to pick $k$ items from $N$, either all $k$ are from $A$, or $k-1$ are from $A$ and $1$ is from $B$, or...)

Has this identity appeared before (I expect the answer to be "Yes!") and if so, does it have a name?

Comment: So-called "alternate" proof: equate coeffients in the identity $(1+x)^a (1+x)^b = (1+x)^{a+b}$.

Comment: In other words: show that the coefficients of the product of two generating functions is the convolution of the coefficients of the two generating functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: Chu-Vandermonde, if we must be complete... ;)