# Sum of products of binomial coefficients is equal to another binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Need help in proving (by induction or by combinatorics) the following statement
[image]

Is it possible to do it by induction? there are 3 veriables and I think I cannot easily do it by induction. Correct? 
I am not sure from where even to begin...

Comment: We can in this case fix two of the variables, say $n$ and $r$ and do an induction on $m$. But the combinatorial argument is I think much clearer.

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68564/is-this-binomial-coefficient-identity-known

Comment: You could also prove it by algebra, i.e., the binomial theorem.

Comment: See also the posts that are Linked to the one above. And [this catalog of binomial sums](http://mathindex.wordpress.com/binomial-sums-without-powers/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Vandermonde Convolution [Vandermonde](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/VandermondeConvolution.shtml)

Comment: Thank you man, you really helped!